# Optimizing mysql subquery for multiple INs

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

Need help speeding up this query. When only one article is in `p.article IN ('200101')` the query runs in 0.0006 sec. If two articles are in `p.article IN ('200101','200102')` the query runs in 0.6414 sec.

Since I need to run this query on about 3000 items I would like to speed it up a little bit. I think the solution is in INNER JOIN, but haven't been able to figure it out myself.

```
SELECT p.article, (
    SELECT s.final_item
    FROM  `structure` s
    WHERE s.item = p.article
    ORDER BY s.level DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS final_item
FROM products p
WHERE p.article IN ('200101','200102')
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `structure.item`?

Comment: Why do you need to run the query 3000 times? If the given query is query 1, what would query2 look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have indexes for article in table products and for item in table structure.

If you always have at least one row in structure for a given product, you could give this a try:

```
SELECT s.final_item, p.article
    FROM  `structure` s INNER JOIN products p ON s.item = p.article
    WHERE s.article IN ('200101','200102')
    ORDER BY s.level DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Limit 1 was now obsolete but rest of the code helped me solve the problem.

Comment: You're welcome, but... Why is now LIMIT 1 obsolete? I thought you needed to retrieve the deepest node in the itmes structure for a given product. If not, there could be a better way to code it. Also, it is important to know if is guaranteed that every article in products has at least a matching row in structure.

Comment: you're right. LIMIT 1 is still necessary. The first page of results only had 1 result each therefore I got the wrong impression.